# Check Box Reset on ListView Scroll

Tags: java, android

my issue is that when I scroll inside of a list view the information gets updated resulting in the checkbox's becoming reset. I need to be able to call an allChecked() function to see if all of the checkboxes are checked but I am unable to do that since there state is being reset. How do I make there state persistent?

here is my custom addpter for handing the list view

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
Context mContext;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext = context;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}

@Override
public DataModel getItem(int position){
    return dataSet.get(position);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View result;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


        result=convertView;
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }
    DataModel item = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.txtName.setText(item.toDo);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(item.checked);


    return result;
 }
}
```

here is my datamodel for storing the list text as well as if its checked or not

```
public class DataModel {
public String toDo;
boolean checked;

DataModel(String toDo, boolean checked){
    this.toDo = toDo;
    this.checked = checked;
 }
}
```

the xml file for the list just in case

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="402dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/GbzBlack"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

and finally how i implement the list view inside of my main

```
   if (formTitle == "215CANNA") {
        Spinner tmpSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bayNameSpinner5);
        TextView tmpTextView = findViewById(R.id.bayNamesText5);
        tmpSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tmpTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //bay 1
        myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(cannaGinB1, getApplicationContext());
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        if (allChecked) {
            nextAndExportBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    buttonCounter++;
                    //bay 2
                    if (buttonCounter == 1) {
                        myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(cannaGinB2, getApplicationContext());
                        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    }
                    //bay 3
                    if (buttonCounter == 2) {
                        myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(cannaGinB3, getApplicationContext());
                        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    }
                    //bay 4
                    if (buttonCounter == 3) {
                        myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(cannaGinB4, getApplicationContext());
                        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        nextAndExportBtn.setText("Export");
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                totalChecked++;
                int listSize = myListView.getCount();
                if (listSize == totalChecked){
                    allChecked = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

changing

```
  viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(item.checked)
```

to

```
 viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(item.checked)
```

makes it so the checkbox stays checked however, upon checking the first checkbox the last checkbox also becomes checked

Comment: I have written code in this article which is quite similar to your issue https://codedotvisible.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

Create an arraylist that can hold a boolean for each case in the listview. When the box is checked save a boolean for each result saying if it was checked or not. So that way when you create the list view before each view is created check if that views boolean is true of false and set the box to checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your thoughts the main fix was to incorporate what Nigel Brown said with the array as well creating an onclicklistner inside of the class instead of outside